# Feedback loop without Subject in RX

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I have the following motion equations

```
move = target_position - position
position = position + move
```

where target_position is a stream and position is initialized at zero. I would like to have a stream of position. I have tried something like this (in rx pseudo code)

```
moves = Subject()
position = moves.scan(sum,0)
target_position.combine_latest(position,diff).subscribe( moves.on_next)
```

It works but I have read that using Subject should be avoided. Is it possible to compute the position stream without Subject?

In python the full implementation looks like this

```
from pprint import pprint 
from rx.subjects import Subject

target_position = Subject()

moves = Subject()

position = moves.scan(lambda x,y: x+y,0.0)

target_position\
    .combine_latest(position,compute_next_move)\
    .filter(lambda x: abs(x)>0)\
    .subscribe( moves.on_next)

position.subscribe( lambda x: pprint("position is now %s"%x))

moves.on_next(0.0)
target_position.on_next(2.0)
target_position.on_next(3.0)
target_position.on_next(4.0)
```

Comment: Is this a drag-and-drop like operation?

Comment: No, it's not gui related.

Comment: Can you please replace the "rx pseudo code" with real c# Rx code please? It's easier to understand exactly what you're doing if we don't have to try to reconstruct your code.

Comment: Apologize, this question was not RX C# specific. I removed the C# tag. I don't code in C#.

Comment: Nonetheless, can you post real javascript/whichever language you are using?

Comment: I added a python implementation.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `position = target_position.startWith(0).filter(lambda x: abs(x)>0)`?  That's all your example code is doing after all.

Comment: I agree with what Brandon said. It doesn't seem like you need a "delta" stream `move` to set `position`. Because `new_position = position + (target - position)` is just `new_position = target`. Basic math

Comment: Yes, the example is too simplistic. I updated it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [expand operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/3f1218340510006a11b93c0c8ae853ac2d2b0121/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md)

```js
targetPosition.combineLatest(position, (target, current) => [target, current])
  .expand(([target, current]) => {
    // if you've reached your target, stop
    if(target === current) {
      return Observable.empty()
    }
    // otherwise, calculate the new position, emit it
    // and pump it back into `expand`
    let newPosition = calcPosition(target, current);
    return Observable.just(newPosition)
  })
  .subscribe(updateThings);
```

Comment: newer link: [rxjs.dev expand()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/expand)